# Automate creation of a pyenv through sh scripts

Tags: pip, dependencies, sh, pyenv, requirements.txt

I'm running a project that uses pip and a requirements.txt file to install and keep track of some dependencies. I want to write some sh scripts to run, build and test the application. For starters I would like a way to check if the current folder is in a pyenv and, if not, create one to enclose the application and not mess around other people's dependencies. Also, I would like an opinion of the best way to keep track of this kind of dependencies, if the requirements.txt is a good approach and if there's a way to keep track of installed versions just like happens with node packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). It's a better way of tracking your depencies than `requirements.txt` and it uses Pyenv to  automatically install your project's required Python version.

From the website:

> The problems that Pipenv seeks to solve are multi-faceted:
>
> - You no longer need to use `pip` and `virtualenv` separately. They work together.
> - Managing a `requirements.txt` file [can be problematic](https://kennethreitz.org/essays/2016/02/25/a-better-pip-workflow), so Pipenv uses `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` to separate abstract dependency
>   declarations from the last tested combination.
> - Hashes are used everywhere, always. Security. Automatically expose security vulnerabilities.
> - Strongly encourage the use of the latest versions of dependencies to minimize security risks [arising from outdated components](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A9-Using_Components_with_Known_Vulnerabilities).
> - Give you insight into your dependency graph (e.g. `$ pipenv graph`).
> - Streamline development workflow by loading `.env` files.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Pipenv Features
>
> - Enables truly *deterministic builds,* while easily specifying *only what you want.*
> - Generates and checks file hashes for locked dependencies.
> - Automatically install required Pythons, if `pyenv` is available.
> - Automatically finds your project home, recursively, by looking for a `Pipfile`.
> - Automatically generates a `Pipfile`, if one doesn’t exist.
> - Automatically creates a `virtualenv` in a standard location.
> - Automatically adds/removes packages to a `Pipfile` when they are installed or uninstalled.
> - Automatically loads `.env` files, if they exist.

Comment: Hello, @MarionRichert thanks for the tip, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if there's a simple way to migrate all the python dependencies from the requirements.txt to work with the Pipenv?

Comment: “If you only have a `requirements.txt` file available when running `pipenv install`, pipenv will automatically import the contents of this file and create a `Pipfile` for you.” https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt

Comment: Don’t forget to click "Accept" on my answer. 